# Cluster validity using KNIME

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, knime

New to using KNIME and wondering what cluster validity measures I can use in it. Any ideas? I was thinking about using the scorer node but not sure how to configure it correctly as when I tried I got an error % of 100

Comment: This might be better asked at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go

Comment: Please don't repost. Questions can be *migrated* instead of duplicating them. And clearly, the KNIME user forums are the much better place to ask... https://tech.knime.org/forum

Comment: I think the place to go will be stats.stackexchange.com. Checking whether knime provides the required functionality is a second step. However, the question in any case will be: which cluster algorithm are you using. In addition I can tell you already know, that it is extremely hard to evaluate the validity of a clustering given that it is an unsupervised training setting.

Comment: @CAFEBABE he already reposted on stats, and it was already closed there.